# How to duplicate feature-linked annotation linked to the same feature class in 9.31?

Tags: arcgis-9.3, annotation

I am trying to make many feature-linked annotation feature classes linked to the same (point) Feature Class, the symbology is exactly the same, but I need separate anno's for users so they can create their own queries and placements.  I don't want to have to re-create all the symbology each time.  The export function is grayed out in AM.  And copy/paste in AC creates a new FC as well (I want them all linked to the same FC), I can't change the relationships either in AC.  Help??  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Feature Class to Feature Class tool in ArcToolbox to make the new copies. Then link them back to the original feature class by creating a 1:M composite relationship class linking the ObjectID field in the base feature class to the FeatureID field in the annotation feature class (refer to the properties on the original relationship class when doing this if you are unsure about any parameters).